# How to mitigate peacecorps.gov DOS attack on bind9 DNS Server?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns, denial-of-service

I newly configured bind9 on my ubuntu server and set `allow-query` to `{ any; }` as I want my DNS server to be accessible for anywhere. However, I am now facing DOS attack using `peacecorps.gov` domain with different IP address. Getting DNS request every seconds. How to mitigate this issue? Is there a way to block DNS lookup for particular website?

My bind9 option configuration

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
    
        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };

        dnssec-validation auto;

        listen-on { any; };
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-recursion { any; };

        version "Forbidden";
};
```

DNS Logs
[image: DNS Log]

Comment: The log shows only about 10 queries per second. That isn't nearly enough to qualify as a DoS attack. If you want to provide DNS resolver service to the world your server needs to be able to handle a much bigger load than that. You'll also want to disable query logging. By the way, please don't include textual information like log excerpts as graphics.

Answer (score 3):

> I newly configured bind9 on my ubuntu server and set `allow-query` to `{ any; }` as I want my DNS server to be accessible for anywhere.

You get exactly what you've configured.
A DNS server that can be used by anybody. Or rather, ***abused*** by anybody and it is being used for abuse right now.

See for example this alert regarding incorrectly configured DNS servers such as yours:

- https://us-cert.cisa.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-088A

---

The only public queries that your DNS server *should* allow and answer, are for the domain names it is authoritative for. (in other words: for your own domain).

If your bind server is to be caching resolver, it should only offer that service to your own servers/subnet, not the whole internet.

Set up an access control list and only allow authorised / trusted clients to use your DNS server and this problem should stop

```
acl myclients {
        192.0.2.0/24;
        localhost;
};


options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
    
        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };

        dnssec-validation auto;

        listen-on { any; };
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        allow-query { myclients; };
        allow-recursion { myclients; };

        version "Forbidden";
};
```